# Selection one "input" with help "radio"

Tags: javascript, forms, input, radio-button

I would like to be able to do only one enabled input type text when selecting for help input type radio.

I can check multiple boxes with a checkbox which works as I want. On this basis, I made a selection using input type radio, which unfortunately does not work properly. Each first selection of radio makes input "always" enabled. And I want only one of the fields that is currently selected to be enabled and the others disabled.

## Code with using input type Checkbox(works correctly)

```
<script>
function disable(checkbox,form){
    if(document.getElementById(checkbox).checked == true){
        document.getElementById(form).disabled = false
    }else{
        document.getElementById(form).disabled = true
    }
}
</script>
<label>Name:<br><input type="checkbox" id="chbx_name" onclick="disable('chbx_name','name')"><input type='text' id="name" name="name" value='<?php echo $row['name'] ?>' disabled></label>
<label>Data:<br><input type="checkbox" id="chbx_data" onclick="disable('chbx_data','data')"><input type='date' id="data" name="data" value='<?php echo $row['data'] ?>' disabled>
</label>
<label>Hour:<br><input type="checkbox" id="chbx_hour" onclick="disable('chbx_hour','hour')"><input type='time' id="hour" name="hour" value='<?php echo $row['hour'] ?>' disabled>
</label>
```

## Code with using input type radio(works incorrectly)

```
<script>
    function disable(radio,form){
        if(document.getElementById(radio).checked == true){
                    document.getElementById(form).disabled = false
        }else{
            document.getElementById(form).disabled = true
        }
    }
</script>
<?php
    $result = $mysqli->query("SELECT picture_name FROM film_pictures WHERE IDpicture = ".$id);
    while($row=$result->fetch_array()){
            $i=0;
            $i++;                                           
                ?><label><input type="radio" id="radio_picture_name<?php echo $i ?>" onclick="disable('radio_picture_name<?php echo $i ?>','picture_name<?php echo $i ?>')"><input type="text" id="picture_name<?php echo $i ?>"  name="picture_name" value="<?php echo $row['picture_name'] ?>" style="width:450px" ></label>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: I'm not a PHP developer but if that's string concatenation you've created a major security issue in your code. Never create database queries using string concatenation otherwise you'll make yourself vulnerable to [SQL injection](https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/SQL_Injection).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first if you need to "turn off" other radio inputs, you have to give them same "name" attribute

```
<script>
    function disable(radio) {
        for (const element of document.getElementsByClassName("picture_name_input")) element.disabled = true;
        radio.closest("label").querySelector("input[type=text]").disabled = false;
    }
</script>
<div class="labels">
    <?php for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) { // Just Replace
        $row = [                        // With your php loop
            "picture_name" => "picture name"
        ];
        ?>
        <label>
            <input type="radio" name="picture_radio" id="radio_picture_name<?php echo $i ?>" 
            onclick="disable(this)"> <!-- as an argument you can give the element by "this" -->
            <input class="picture_name_input" type="text" id="picture_name<?php echo $i ?>" name="picture_name" value="<?php echo $row['picture_name'] ?>" style="width:450px">
        </label>
    <?php } ?>
</div>
```

if i understand right this can help you :)

Comment: Now it is working. I'm making a project using php and I don't know javascript well, I only want to use it to select inputs. I knew about i should add name to input radio, only restore to previous working version and I made reconstruction what I did before and forgot about it. Very thanks! :)